# Есть ли общий второстепенный член предложения в ССП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, семантика, ссп

***В городе не было гостиницы и мы остановились в какой-то пустовавшей квартире из нескольких комнат.***

Считаю, что запятая нужна, так как предложения имеют следственную связь:

***В городе не было гостиницы, и (поэтому) мы остановились в какой-то пустовавшей квартире из нескольких комнат.***

Однако интересно услышать, почему варианта с ОВЧ не может быть (разные виды глаголов дают право не рассматривать сочетание как ОВЧ?).

Comment: Алексей, о каком обособлении ОВЧ идет речь? И пишете, что запятая не нужна, но поставили ее, где "поэтому".

Comment: Страшная очепятка, извиняюсь)

Comment: Ничего, бывает... Ну так "обособление ССП" тоже не то. Напишите "запятая в ССП..." А вообще, как мне кажется, вопрос должен касаться именно того, есть ли здесь ОВЧ. // А что с глаголами? Вроде оба в прошедшем времени, всё нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил)

Comment: Может, потому, что вторая часть не очень звучит с "в городе": *В городе мы остановились в какой-то пустовавшей квартире из нескольких комнат.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы правы, запятая нужна. ***В городе*** не тянет на общий второстепенный член. Чтобы "объединиться", предложения в составе ССП должны быть более или менее равноправными, а в данном случае, как Вы правильно заметили, есть явная причинно-следственная связь. А глаголы здесь ни на что не влияют.

Ответ на [одном из сайтов по ЕГЭ](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=29821) однозначный:

> 1)  [В городе не было гостиницы], и [мы остановились в какой-то пустовавшей квартире из нескольких комнат]. − *Запятая между основами.*

Интересно, зачем составители тестов изменили порядок слов? Чтобы навести на мысль об ОВЧ и тем самым запутать? Ведь оригинальное предложение, вообще-то, выглядит так:

*Гостиницы в городе не было, и мы остановились в какой-то пустовавшей квартире из нескольких комнат...* (Обручев В. А., «Мои путешествия по Сибири», сайт [ЛитЛайф](https://litlife.club/books/92238/read?page=60))

И здесь уже не возникает такого вопроса.

Comment: Интересно и спрашивалось, почему не тянет.

Comment: @oleedd Вы ответили в комментарии.

Comment: Ну а вы не ответили, на главный вопрос... Может, это не основная причина.

Comment: @oleedd  Отвечайте сами, а то только поучаете всех.

Comment: Моё маленькое предположение в комментарии. Для ответа этого мало.

Comment: Если вы не соглашаетесь с кем-то, то давайте конструктивную критику. Поначалу вы пытались, но потом ситуация прояснилась, а вы продолжаете не соглашаться, когда уже всё просто и возразить вам уже нечего (против правды не попрёшь). Неприятно это. Удалю позже. И в общем, не все проблемы тянут на то, чтобы считаться ошибкой. Так что не надо так трястись за это.

Comment: @oleedd Глупости. Ситуация там мне была ясна с самого начала. Вы постоянно втягиваете в многословные препирания, якобы устанавливающие истину. Никакой "правды" я не увидел, всё по тому же месту. Образность речи писателя не видите, шум листвы не ощущаете, какие-то математические структуры выводите...

Comment: Правильность — это узкий круг. Люди постоянно пытаются за него выйти, не хотят никаких ограничений и хотят свободу. Особенно вы и Sharon. Это не то, как должны мыслить лингвисты и люди, которые к ним стремятся. Это смысловая схема, не структура. Неужели у вас 0 научного мышления. "Глупости" — это как "фильм фигня", за такое в интернете уже троллят. Понять можно по-разному (многосмысленность), тишина и шум диссонируют, с "и" повторяется сказанное (тоже), а не новое говорится, смысловая схема соответствует предложению. Это всё верно, глупости называть это глупостями. Но нужна свобода, плюнем...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Знаешь, Саша, с этими ОВЧ (в городе, в лесу)... Мы ж не авторы — только предполагаем, рассуждаем, как-нибудь видим... И ведь писатель ощущает по-своему.  И без контекста иногда никак не обойтись.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, но здесь и контекст не поможет, так как предложение переделали.

Comment: Ну да, ну да... По памяти, приблизительно (еще со студенчества; где-то есть, но сейчас не найду и за точность не ручаюсь): *Ученик упражняется, решает пример за примером, выражение упрощается тем или этим манером: умножается, переносится, привычно за скобки выносится, соблазнительно сокращается — из сосны бревно получается...*